# Showing that some basic algebraic expressions hold for given real variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equations and expressions (note that all variables involved below are real numbers):

$ a_1 = \cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{1+p^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}}$,
$ a_2 = \cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{2}$,
$ b_1 = \cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{p+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}}$,
$ b_2 = \cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{2p}$

$a_1 + a_2 = 2w_1$ and $b_1 + b_2 = 2w_2$

All the variables excluding $\gamma$ are positive ($\gamma < 0$):

I am asked to show the following algebraic expressions hold:

1. $p < \cfrac{w_1}{w_2}$
2. $a_1 > a_2$
3. $|a_1-a_2| < |b_1-b_2|$

My attempt to show $(1)$:

$$\cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{p+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}}+\cfrac{w_1 + p.w_2}{2p} = 2w_2$$
$$2p(w_1+p.w_2)+p+(p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}})(w_1+p.w_2)=2p(p+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}})2w_2$$
$$3pw_1+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}w_1+3p^2 w_2 + p.p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}w_2=4p^2 w_2 + 4p.p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}} w_2$$
$$3pw_1+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}} w_1 = p^2 w_2+ 3p.p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}w_2$$
$$w_1(3p+p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}})=(p^2+3p.p^{\frac{-1}{\gamma-1}}) w_2$$
$$p\left(\cfrac{1+\frac{3}{p^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}}{3+p^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}\right)=\cfrac{w_1}{w_2}$$

I'm stuck here. Am I on the right track? I am open to any help for the remaining steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how much it will help, but you can simplify your last expression by using common denominator for the numerator in parenthesis. I am also wondering if you need to simultaneously use the same approach for $b$'s

Comment: Yes, indeed simplifying would help. I will do it, thanks. However, for the first part, all i need to show that $p\left(\cfrac{1+\frac{3}{p^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}}{3+p^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}\right)$ is less than $p$. So, I am looking for any algebraic tricks here.

Comment: You have an expression of $p$ and $\gamma$ that must be less than $1$. It seems to me like that there is a domain of values where this is true, but not for every combination. The second equation might provide a constraint.

Comment: In your last step, the exponent suddenly switches from $\frac {-1}{\gamma -1}$ to $\frac {\gamma}{\gamma -1}$, which does not appear to be justified. Correct that and let $\alpha = p^{-1/(\gamma-1)}$. Inequality (1) is true $\iff$ the coefficient of $p$ is $> 1$  $\iff 3 + \alpha < 1 + \frac 3\alpha$ $\iff \alpha^2 + 2\alpha - 3 < 0$. Thus $\alpha < 1$, which is true exactly when $p < 1$, which is also equivalent to inequality (2). Perhaps you can get that from $a_1 + a_2 = 2w_1$